# Can I generate a SSL certificate with only WordPress admin account?

Tags: wordpress, ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I want to setup SSL for a client but all they have is a WordPress admin account.  No domain account/email, no hosting account, no cPanel account and no FTP/SSH access. Is it possible?  It's on a shared host and the original guy charge a lot.

I'm planning to use Let's Encrypt.

Comment: Does the site have a public URL? Normally SSL certificates are added to the web server so depending on how the site is setup it maybe possible. Like one-click sites have this feature normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to add an SSL with "only" WordPress access. However, you may have more access than you have told us. For example, if you have access to your site's DNS, you could run your DNS through CloudFlare or a similar service and get an SSL solution there.